# VS Code launch location of git bash

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I have recently changed the default terminal to use when in VS Code to `git bash` by setting the value of `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` in `settings.json` to `"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`.

Problem is that whenever I press the shortcut key it launches at home `~` folder instead of the current working folder.

Is there a setting you can change to alter this behavior?

I'm using Windows 10 and VS Code version 1.9.1

Comment: I'm starting to think there's no such setting. I have been through the documentation and there's nothing. Even in the settings.json itself. I think the only way to achieve the desired behaviour is to first of all be in a project folder/file.

Answer (score 1):

As in [this project](https://github.com/chintan3/vscodetest), you can call a wrapper instead of git bash directly. Or you [can pass a parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7266).

But the problem is to know the current folder, and this is not yet supported, as illustrated [by the issues on that topic](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/search?q=%22current%20folder%22&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: I think this is simply a work-around. A nice one a that. According to you there isn't a setting that can be changed?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find any setting for that, hence the workaround

Comment: I didn't either. Made a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on VS Code 1.10.2 and it opens to current working folder. Only other difference is the path I'm using for the terminal is "C:\Windows\sysnative\bash.exe". Try upgrading VS Code and/or editing the path in your settings.